# How to calculate isotopic power of radon?

Tags: radiation, isotopes

I read that  [radioisotope thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator#Criteria_for_selection_of_isotopes) run off of isotopes that produce alpha particles.  I see that various fuels such as polonium-210 are categorized by "isotopic power".

Radon is not listed among isotopic fuels for these thermoelectric generators, I think because of the short half life.  How would one calculate isotopic power for radon (or any other alpha emitter)?

Comment: -1. Insufficient research effort. Have you looked up the definition of isotopic power? eg  https://www.nucleonica.com/wiki/index.php/Isotopic_power.

Comment: Radon also has the downside of being a gas, not a solid, making it harder to have a lot of it in a small volume. But, given the half life and known alpha energy the calculation follows in the same way as Po-210.

Comment: Perhaps a better question for the OP that *"Did you search that?"* is *"What did you find unclear about the material presented in the sources you looked at?"*. Because this is not a difficult concept, but it is often told in the jargon of the field which can be opaque to outsiders. Though of course, if your problem was with the jargon then you should have *asked about the jargon* lest you get people onto the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the energy E released in the decay.

Calculate the activity:

$$A=\ln(2)*\frac{n}{t_{1/2}}$$

where n is the amount of substance and $t_{1/2}$ the half life.

The isotopic power is
$$P=A\frac{E}{n}$$ 
in W/mol.

If you multiply with atomic mass you get
$$P=M A \frac{E}{n}$$
in W/g

Consider that some energy may escape unused, e.g. as neutrinos or maybe neutrons. You'll also have to convert E from eV to J.

Edit: If you don't find the decay energy you may calculate it by $E=mc^2$ where m is the mass defect (how much less mass the products of the decay have than the original isotope).